# Setting State after an API call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setState after an API call. I am looping through a fetch call to retrieve data but for some reason, if I console.log(this) it will show my data in this.state.data but if I console.log(this.state.data) or (this.data) I have an empty array.

```
 fetchData = (url, index) => {
      fetch(url + index * 100)
      .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => 
          this.setState({
            data: result
          }))}





searchChar = () => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
        logo: false,
        notFound: false,
      })

      let value = this.state.basicAddon1.toLowerCase();
      const foundSearch = [];
      const comics = [];
      const url = this.state.url;
      const offsetLimit = 5;
      const searchIndex = value.charAt(0)  
      let searchUrl = url.replace("tempKey", searchIndex);


          for(let apiSearch = 0; apiSearch < offsetLimit; apiSearch++){
            this.fetchData(searchUrl, apiSearch);

console.log(this) - Gets data back if I search the log and go to state and data
console.log(this.state) - Gets undefined 
console.log(this.data) - Get undefined
```

Comment: You should add your console.logs in the code.  Hard to know where the problem is if we can't see where you're logging.  You should add your constructor as well to confirm that your state is set up correctly.

Comment: Are you getting data back from your API?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated with where my console.logs are at.

Answer (score 0):

So there are actually a couple things going on here.

Firstly, notice how you are setting `this.state.data` to result. This means that every time this function is run, `this.state.data` is going to be overwritten. You might want to turn data into a list of objects.

Secondly, notice that `fetchData` uses fetch which is asynchronous. This means that the function will not wait for the fetch to complete before returning. So what happens, is in your loop, the function is ran a couple times and before `setState` is called, you are logging. To solve this, wait for all the data to resolve before continuing.

*fetchData*

```
fetchData = async (url, index) => {
  await fetch(url + index * 100)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => 
      this.setState({
        data: result // You may want to the replace this line considering the first issue
       })
    )
}
```

*searchChar*

```
searchChar = async () => {
   ...

   var dataFetchPromises = []
   for(let apiSearch = 0; apiSearch < offsetLimit; apiSearch++){
        dataFetchPromises.push(this.fetchData(searchUrl, apiSearch))

    await Promise.all(dataFetchPromises)

   ...
}
```

Comment: Okay so everything makes sense but the list of objects. Am I still using setState or what is the best way to store the data?

Comment: You are still going to be using `setState`. `setState(prevState => ({ data: [...prevState.data, result] }))`. Make sure the initial state to data is `[]`.